# Are there any interfaces shared by value types representing numbers?

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to be able to create various structures with variable precision. For example:

```
public struct Point<T> where T : INumber
{
    public T X;
    public T Y;

    public static Point<T> operator +(Point<T> p1, Point<T> p2)
    {
        return new Point<T>
                   {
                       X = p1.X+p2.X,
                       Y = p1.Y+p2.Y
                   };
    }
}
```

I know Microsoft deals with this by creating two structures - `Point` (for integers) and `PointF` (for floating point numbers,) but if you needed a byte-based point, or double-precision, then you'll be required to copy a lot of old code over and just change the value types.

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322383/why-dont-number-types-not-share-a-common-interface/4322432#4322432

Comment: Didnt know you could overload operators in C#... Nice! +rep'ing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple reason why you cannot do that: Operators are non-virtual, i.e., the compiler must know *at compile time* whether `p1.X+p2.X` is an integer addition or a double addition.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler know at compile time what T is, though? Maybe it shouldn't work like an interface, but it would be a nice language feature of C# - the ability to force T to be a number, so that you can use +, -, * and /.

Comment: @Daniel: No, it doesn't know the type of T at compile time... you might be developing a library, so the compiler cannot know *which* T your customers will pass to your class.

Comment: Good point about the library - I know just enough about generics to be dangerous. That's too bad, though. They should look into some solution for C# 5.0, because this would be really handy.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such interface.